# Ansys structural optimization solution problem，I was stucked with this for three days

Tags: optimization, ansys

When ANSYS was solving for structural optimization, this appeared:‘The optimization solution run was terminated.The input file"Parameter.txt" is missing.’，then I checked the solution information，which told me：
*** ERROR ***
No solver name provided or solver not supported.

*** ERROR ***
Missing parameter file.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kKzl.png)

I was stucked with this for three days，can anyone help me，Your help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Please, clarify your problem, for example, which solver is chosen, problem statement, mathematical model of the process.

Comment: hi,thanks for your comment so much,the solver i have chosen was programm control,and the solution error was 'The optimization solution run was terminated.The input file "Parameter.txt" is missing',I will check the mathematical model，I‘lltell you soon. by the way have you click the 'enter image description here' and get some useful information

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. A solution is probably to save the part as an .igs file. I am using solidworks for designing and ansys for the analysis.